# Referencing .htpasswd from accounts with different usernames

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-auth

I push my website to multiple servers where I have different usernames. I want to have a `.htaccess` file that password protects a file regardless of which server I'm on.

The issue is that [`AuthUserFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html#authuserfile) only takes absolute paths, so if I have:

```
AuthUserFile /home/will/.htpasswd
```

I get a server error on a box where my username is wjholcomb (and home directory is /home/wjholcomb/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.htaccess` can have multiple `AuthUserFile` lines:

```
AuthUserFile /home/will/.htpasswd
AuthUserFile /home/wjholcomb/.htpasswd
```

Comment: If the first file on the list doesn't exist, internal server error occurs. So, how to deploy one `.htaccess` file on different servers then?